# Unity 3D freezing after leaving Game Mode (MRTK)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, windows-mixed-reality

I've been working in a project some weeks now in a Mixed Reality project using Unity and MRTK and I've found a strange behaviour when adding screen capture to the application. I'm using **Unity 2019.4.26f1**, and I haven't found any issues so far but after adding this line of code

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("test.png");
```

into a script, I've realised that when I press Play and go into Game mode, everything goes correctly (the game starts, the screenshot is taken). **BUT** when I stop it and try to go into Play mode again, Unity freezes. If I don't press Play again, Unity still works until it tries to compile scripts or some heavy task like that, when it freezes and can only be closed with the task manager.

If I remove that line, Unity goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue cannot be reproduced in Unity 2020.3 LTS. Does this happen when the remoting play or in Editor? According to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20203-lts-recommended), if you target to HoloLens 2, please upgrade to the recommended 2020.3 LTS version that is stated in the document.

In addition, ScreenCapture is a Unity built-in class and if there are any usage questions, you may find support from [Unity forum](https://answers.unity.com/index.html).

Comment: It happens in both modes. I cannot upgrade the version of the editor (I tried, but the incompatibilities with the project cause it to break).

Comment: Would you use MCR to capture pictures? -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/holographic-photos-and-videos

Comment: This could be a valid workaround, detecting the screenshot attending to gestures or speech and retrieve that file, thank you.